# There is an array array1=[20,10,4,3,8,9,30]. There result array should have the immediate next number of the main array. i.e array2=[30,20,8,4,9,30]

Tags: python

There is an array array1=[20,10,4,3,8,9,30]. There result array should have the immediate next number of the main array. i.e array2=[30,20,8,4,9,30]. Is there any better way to do this? Like O(n) solution

```
def two_string():
        a = [20,10,4,3,8,9,30]
        b = []
        count1 = count2 = 0
        for i in range (len(a)-1):
            for j in range(i, len(a)):
                if a[i]<a[j]:
                    count1 = a[j]
                    b.append(count1)
                    break

        print b

two_string()
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Firstly, you do not have any strings, but your function ls called `two_string`. What is "_the immediate next number_"?

Comment: How is your current attempt O(n)? Why do you expect this to be a problem which you can solve in O(n)?

Comment: Your code produces a complete different answer from what you say you want (`[30, 30, 8, 8, 9, 30]`), which makes it even harder to guess what you're trying to implement.

Comment: @DyZ, he means the next larger in the entire list by size. For example, 30 is the next larger number than 20, 20 is the next larger number than 10, etc.

Comment: @jpp Then why is there no 10 in the 6th position? And a 30 in the last position?

Comment: @DyZ, *seems* like an edge case.. There is no "next larger number than 30", so it defaults to 30..

Comment: @jpp And no 10? Seems like too many assumptions.

Comment: @DyZ, yep that seems an error. I think abamert has what he's asking for. But the main point is I don't think O(n) is ever possible.

Comment: @jpp Well, if we can assume that the domain of values is "small integers" for some reasonable definition of small that doesn't scale with `N` in any way, we could do the sorting in `O(N)` time. It's possible that's what the OP was hoping for. (If so, the example is pretty misleading, because the domain is closer to `N**2` than `N`… but given the other problems with the example, I wouldn't rule out that was his intention.)

Answer (score 4):

You can do what I think you want in `O(N log N)` time, which is better than your `O(N**2)`, but not linear, and it takes `O(N)` extra space:

```
>>> a = [20,10,4,3,8,9,30]
>>> sa = sorted(a)
>>> pairs = dict(zip(sa, sa[1:]))
>>> [pairs.get(x, x) for x in a]
[30, 20, 8, 4, 9, 10, 30]
```

This doesn't actually match either your requested output, or the output of the `O(N**2)` code you say does what you want, but I think it's what you're asking for anyway.

---

Here's how it works:

For each number, we need to know the next higher number. If we had a dict that maps each number to the next higher one, we could look them each up in constant time instead of linear. But how do we get that dict? If we sort the list, which takes log-linear time, it's just a matter of mapping each number to the next one, which you can do by making a list of adjacent pairs from the sorted list, and then turning that into a dict.

The only problem is what to do about the biggest number. It appears you want that to map to itself, so we can use `pairs.get(x, x)` instead of `pairs[x]`.

---

Can we do better? In general, no. Finding the next value in sorted order after every value is going to be equivalent to sorting the whole list, even if we avoid an explicit sort. The only way you could do better is to take advantage of some property of your values that makes it possible to sort more quickly. For example, if the list could range from length 1 to length 1 zillion, but all of the values are always going to be integers in `range(100)`, you can sort that in `100*N` steps, which is linear. But without such a guaranteed property to take advantage of, you can't.

Comment: This is a really ingenious solution, props for using `.get(x, x)`!